# how many green fly could there be by the end of day 28? Please check the program if it is the correct solution

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, sum, series

Green
y can reproduce asexually. After one week of life a lone female can produce eight
ospring a day. Starting at the beginning of day 1 with a single mature female, how many
green
y could there be by the end of day 28? It may be assumed that:
 There are no deaths
 All ospring are females
Note that at the end of day 1 there will be 9 green
y (original + 8 ospring). At the end
of day 7 there will be 57 green
y (original + 8  7 ospring). At the end of day 8 there
will be 129 green
y (original + 8  8 ospring + 64 ospring from the daughters produced
on day 1).

```
package questions;
public class Solutions{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=1;
    int b=0;
    int c=0;
    int d[]= new int[28];
    d[0]=1;
    for(int i=0; i<28; i++){

        if(i<8) {
            if(i==1 || i==0)d[i]=a+a*8;
            else {
            d[i]= d[i-1] + 8;
            c=d[i];
            }
        }else {
            d[i]=d[i-1]+ d[i-7]*8;
            int temp= d[i]*8;
            c+=temp;

        }

    }
    System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no question?

Comment: I mean, is the program correct? like I could not find the exact answer to the question.